# Customer form Allignment issue in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I had created a template for Customer address form.
There is alignment issue with name block and phone number block.
As shown in below image

[image]

This thing works fine on my development environment but creating issue on production site

```
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Contact Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSuccessUrl()) ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getErrorUrl()) ?>">
    <?= $block->getNameBlockHtml() ?>

    <?php if ($_telephone->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_telephone->setTelephone($block->getAddress()->getTelephone())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($_company->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_company->setCompany($block->getAddress()->getCompany())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($_fax->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_fax->setFax($block->getAddress()->getFax())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Are you working on live project if yes can you share the link or localhost ?